# Vertical space of span expands in the containing div when it's set to be an inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have a span embedded in a div like this :

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 50px;
}
span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

It works well. However, if I set the span to be `display:inline-block`, the background color of the span expands to fill up the vertical space of the div. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `span` by default is an *inline* element. As soon as it becomes an inline-block`, its height will adjust to the full line-height.

In the following example I created two inline-block spans and left the third one at the default `inline`. The first inherits the `line-height` 50px from the container, the second has a defined line-height of 40px, which is less than the line-height of the container and therefore leaves some vertical space above and below. The third again has the `inline` property (which would be the default if `span` were not defined as `inline-block` before) and only covers height of the text itself since it's `inline`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjAPqg

```
<div>
  <span>text1 inline-block line-height 50px</span>
  <span class="span2">text2 inline-block line-height 40px</span>
  <span class="span3">text3 inline</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
       div {
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px;
          background: red;
          line-height: 50px;
        }

        span {
          background: yellow;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .span2 {
          background: green;
          display: inline-block;
          line-height: 40px;
        }
        .span3 {
          background: aqua;
          display: inline;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your span will inherit the div's `line-height`, and will try to adjust its height to it.